# iPhone: Core Data, How to get sum of values from db

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a model 'Pens' and it has such properties: "makerName" and "Count". How can I get sum of all 'Count' ? Can Core Data count that for me ? Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:
first - get your data to NSSet or NSArray and use @sum operator:

```
//assume that `pens` are NSArray of Pen
NSNumber *countSum=[pens valueForKeyPath:"@sum.count"];
```

second is using specific fetch [for specific value](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6) with added [NSExpressionDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForFunction:arguments:) with a sum. This way is harder but better for larger db's

Comment: Grate, I like first way. And what if Pens have one more property 'Color' and I want to count sum of red pens ?

Comment: Simply build array only with red pens using NSPredicate, and sum up this array.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can get those from core data, rather than fetching and evaluating the results. You can perform functions such as sum on the core data by use of NSExpression.

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"Count"];
NSExpression *sumOfCountExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                              arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

For a list of functions that you can use go here

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html.

You then need to create an NSExpressionDescription object where you set the expression tho the sumOfCountExpression that you just created.

```
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"sumOfCount"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:sumOfCountExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];
```

Then construct your requests as you would usually and then set the property to fetch to that expression.

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
```

Refer: [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1)

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to set the resultType on the NSFetchRequest to be NSDictionaryResultType, and that the value returned will be in the returned dictionary under the key 'sumOfCount', or whatever you set in the setName above.

Comment: @ScottAllen: Thanks! That was crashing and driving me bonkers, and this answer is the second description of how to do this I've seen that  omits this tiny important detail!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the SQL equivalent you want is:

```
select sum(p.count) 
from pens p 
where makerName = '{whatever maker you are querying for}'
```

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157377/how-to-use-sum-with-coredata) for the code you're looking for.