# IOS/Objective-C: Sum Integer in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, sum

I am trying to get the sum of an NSNumber attribute from core data.  According to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157377/how-to-use-sum-with-coredata), all you need to do is put some code in the NSManagedObject class for the entity.  However, when I try to access this method, I get a wrong answer, namely 0 when I know the sum should be higher than that.

Is it correct that the following code is a good way to 'get' a sum from core data?  And, if so, what is the proper way to call it as I am not getting a valid sum?

Thanks for any suggestions.

For Class named Points with an Integer64 attribute named points

```
.h file
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber* sumPoints;

.m file
-(NSNumber*) sumPoints
{
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"Points.@sum.points"];
}

Calling from another class that imports this class:
 return [_Points.sumPoints intValue];
//Is returning 0 when sum should be much higher
```

Comment: This won't do it. You will certainly need to use an `NSExpression` and `NSFetchRequest` or to load all records and then use key-value-coding with `@sum`.

Comment: what values are you trying to sum? is there relationship that you are not showing?