# Is this the best way to set CoreData entity variables to 0 every day at 24:00?

Tags: swift, core-data

I currently have a coreData entity called CalorieProgress, which I would like to reset all variables (calorieProgress, fatProgress) to 0, every day.

I am still quite new to SwiftUI, and the only method I thought of as of now, is to add a Date Created variable to this entity called created, and when the user opens the app, to check if that date was yesterday. If so set all values to 0 etc.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is good and simple, and a reasonable choice if you're getting started.

It can have trouble, however, when people move between time zones. It is even possible for people to move to previous days this way (most dramatically when they cross the date line). There is no single answer to that question. Your app has to decide what it means by "today" when strange clock events happen. (Users also sometimes change their clock, and you want to behave "reasonably" in those cases, even if it means the data is wrong.)

Having built several of these, my suggestion is to just store raw, immutable, data records, and work out things like resetting values when you're running queries. For example, to work out how many calories someone has burned "today" doesn't require that you set any value to zero. You can just perform a query for records that occur after some time and sum their calories (you can even do this with [aggregate queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157377/how-to-use-sum-with-coredata) directly on Core Data).

Core Data can be very fast, but if these queries become too slow, you can store daily aggregation records in Core Data. But keeping the original raw data means that those are really just caches and you can throw them away and recompute any time you need to.

Assuming that a new day starts as midnight (I've worked on apps where days started "when the user wakes up in the morning" which is *much* more complicated...) you should also be aware of `significantTimeChangeNotification` which is posted at midnight (and a few other times). You can't use this to launch your app or do processing in the background, but it's very nice for updating your UI if the user has the app open.

Comment: Wow Rob, I should be saying thanks but I am now slightly overwhelmed! Truly appreciate the info! :)

Comment: :D Start simple! Don't let all these corner cases get in the way of you getting some code running and seeing how your app evolves. You can always go back and make it better! Best of luck.